# Changing the output position based on unique occurrences

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is an example spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1biUH0Uws1YOmzc2LKLFNPW0kchxHDdcnNezXdRfZyAo/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using the formula: =TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(D2:D10, (B2:B10="XD") * (A2:A10="L1")))) to filter and select items in column D where B = "XD". The result I want is to have a blank space in between the q1, q7 output based on the fact TP2 does not have "XD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=TOROW(MAP(UNIQUE(C1:C9),LAMBDA(tp,IFNA(FILTER(D1:D9,"L1"=A1:A9,"XD"=B1:B9,tp=C1:C9)))))
```

[image]